# Set a default value in wpf textbox and c#

Tags: c#, wpf

How am i going to set a default value (number) to my textbox in my wpf? That whenever a open up the window with that order textbox, it should have a default value 1. Then save it. Then the next time I open again the window, the order number will increment to 1 so it will become 2. Please give me an example. Thanks a lot.. Looking forward with your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, you should be using MVVM, which means that text box is databound.

Since it is databound, all you need to do to set the default value is set the bound object's properties to what you want.

To get the auto-increment is kind of tricky. At a basic level, you could just set a variable on the first form (or in a global static if you really have to) and increment it with each order. You would then set the value to the `Order` object's ID field before passing it to the order form view model for display.

Of course, that only works for one run of your program, so you may want to insert your new order object into your database, then select the IDENTITY column or if using EF, just grab the ID of the inserted item. Of course this means you have a default object in your DB for a while.

Comment: @BradleyDotBET Can you give me a sample code on how am i going to implement this? I am using database..

Comment: @iamkcdavid That depends on how far along you are. Do you already have your bindings set up? What are you using for your ORM? I'm happy to provide sample code to clarify, but I'm not going to write the whole thing. Basically, the code required is broad enough that I would like to know which piece is confusing you.

Comment: @iamkcdavid great! so I can skip that part. Is it just the auto-increment you are wondering about then? Are you already set up with an IDENTITY column? What ORM are you using?

Comment: @BradleyDotBET yes thats it. Just the auto increment. However, i have this king of code.. 

'int i = 1;
            if (int.TryParse(txtOrder.Text, out i))
            {
                txtOrder.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            }'

However, when I open up the window, theres no default value in the textbox name order.

Comment: That code isn't using databinding, and to get a correct auto-increment, you'll want to get the next ID that the database will use (hence me asking about your ORM). Make sure you are setting the *backing property* instead of directly modifying the UI.

Comment: For the textbox order, i use databind to bind the text that i input to it then view it my GridviewPage. Something like, i just need to call my textbox and set a property that will give a default value to it and it will auto increment when an another order will be added.

Comment: @iamkcdavid Right. *Nothing will automatically do that* you need to set the ID property of the bound `Order` object yourself. To do this accurately, you need to utilize the DB. If this doesn't make sense, perhaps we could talk in chat sometime tomorrow?

Comment: what do you mean chat? As in in skype? Something like that?

Comment: No, in StackOverflow chat. If you are available between 9 and 5 PST tomorrow, I'll set it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62352/discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-iamkcdavid).

Comment: Tried to find you in chat. Let me know if you still need help,.